# 'func' Positional argument - Discord.py Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord

so I'm making a Python bot for Discord and I'm receiving an odd error (and I also have another enquiry after this):

```
TypeError: decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

I'm not sure what is causing it. The way I have the file tree setup for the project is like so:

```
├───.idea
├───handlers
│   └───userHandler.py
└───src
    └───main.py
```

It's pointing me to line 23 to my `on_message` method inside `main.py` here (whole method):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(client.command_prefix + 'tstring'):
        client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello, ' + str(userHandler.getuser()))
```

Line 23 is this one here:

`client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello, ' + str(userHandler.getuser()))`

The `userHandler` method is located in `userHandler.py` as shown in the tree above:

```
@client.command
async def getuser(user, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = user.message.author
        client.say('{0}'.format(member))
```

The user handler file is seperate from the main because I want to handle all user-based commands within their own system. I will be using the same logic towards commands in it's own handler also.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible/ideal to write the commands in a different file away from main.py and still call them in main to be used? If so, do I need to write `@client.command` every time I call a command in `main.py` from `commandHandler.py` even if it's in the `commandHandler.py` file already? Or is there a more optimal method for this? (not sure if that makes enough sense)
2. Am I just missing an argument in the error above? I'm not taking the Discord.py API very well at the moment. If not, what is the issue? I really hope I'm damn stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes you can write commands in a separate file and have them still register to main. In discord.py, this is called using cogs. Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/leovoel/46cd89ed6a8f41fd09c5).

There are a couple issues with your code assuming that's exactly how you have it. Firstly, you must always `await` coroutine functions in order to use them -> `await client.send_message("Hello")`... `await client.say("Hello")` Secondly, I'm not exactly sure creating a "userhandler" is a good idea. Especially the way you're attempting to considering there are easier more straightforward ways to get a user object.

Lastly, please refer to the link I posted above to see how the `@client.command()` decorator is used.

Comment: Even if I'm using await, it still doesn't work at all and I just get another error come up if I put `await` infront of `client.send_message` inside `main.py`. I'm guessing just because of poor code.

I've taken note however, the `@client` decorator I understand more.